# Dividir resultados de una consulta en dos posiciones diferentes en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Necesito dividir el resultado de una consulta en dos posiciones diferentes las posiciones serian las siguientes:

```
<table>
        <tr>

      <td>Aqui el 50% de los resultados</td>
      <td> Aqui otro tipo de contenido</td>
       <td>Y aqui el otro 50% de los resultados</td>

        </tr>
        </table>
```

Alguna idea ?

Comment: y si nos muestras que tipo de consulta estas haciendo? de otro modo tu pregunta es muy vaga en formato y contenido

Comment: es  esta consulta `$mothers = Tpda::where('di', $id)->select('parentesco_id')->get();`

Comment: nadie ? sigo googleando pero no doy con nada..